# Trying to log users with wp_signon()

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm doing a whole new login form in Wordpress. 
I can register users but the wp_signon does not work at all. 
Users are well registered because i can log them on the classic /wp-admin but not on my custom one. 
I have an error like that :

> WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [empty_password] => Array ( [0] => Erreur : le champ du mot de passe est vide. ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )

Where "Erreur : le champ du mot de passe est vide." means "Error : the password field is empty".

Here is my code :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name : Connexion
*/

$error = false;

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $userlog = array(
        'user_login' => $_POST['user_login'],
        'user_pass' => $_POST['user_password'],
    );
    $user = wp_signon($userlog);
    do_action('init', $user);
    if(is_wp_error($user)){
        $user->get_error_message();
        print_r($user);
    }else{
        header("Location: /");
    };
}

get_header();?>

<div class="main_container">

    <div class="container_form">

        <h2>Se connecter</h2>
        <div class="form_logo">

        </div>

        <?php if($error) {?>
        <div class="error">
            <?php echo $error ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" method="POST">

            <label for="user_login">Identifiant</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login">

            <label for="user_password">Mot de passe</label>
            <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password">

            <div id="button_container">
                <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Se connecter" id='save'/>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have tried do call it on init, without init... Lot of things !
Thanks if you can help.

EDIT

The error came from the 'user_pass' it has to be 'user_password' for the wp_signon and 'user_pass' for wp_insert_user

Here is the register page on which the user is registered but not log in.

```
$error = false;

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    if($_POST['user_password'] != $_POST['user_password2']) {
        $error = "Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas";
    } else {
        if(!is_email($_POST['user_email'])) {
            $error = "Veuillez entrer un email valide";
        } else {
            $user = array(
                'user_login' => $_POST['user_login'],
                'user_pass' => $_POST['user_password'],
                'user_email' => $_POST['user_email'],
            );
            $user_add = wp_insert_user($user);
            if (is_wp_error($user_add)) {
                $error = $user_add->get_error_message();
            } else {
                update_field('player_league_of_legends', $_POST['user_login'], 'user_'.$user_add);
                $user_login = wp_signon($user);
                do_action('template_redirect', $user_login);
                if(is_wp_error($user_login)){
                    $error = $user_login->get_error_message();
                } else {
                    header("Location: /login");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The password for `wp_signon` is supposed to be stored in the `user_password` key of the array

Answer (score 0):

This code is in index.php?

According to documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/ you must use wp_signon in function.php.

You can also use plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login/#developers or by inspired by him

Comment: Nop, it's in a custom plugin. So i have no way to log someone from a custom plugin ? Thanks a lot by advance :)

Comment: All is hook in WP and when you POST a form they are probably an attempt to login before your code. 

It's hard to follow the stack call. 

If you change in form user_password by pwd and user_login by log you should have no error.

Comment: It seems to work on a login page now, just changed the user_pass to user_password. Now it does not on my register. The user is registered but isn't log in. I have edit with the register page.

Comment: Hello, you can try this https://gist.github.com/zeppi/45af6568f3e048c82358dc1161aa1096